# CHttpRequest and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getRawBody" (Yii v1.1.8)

Tags: php, http, yii, frameworks, httprequest

I am running Yii v1.1.8 (not the latest I know but it is a legacy project). I am getting the following error when I run the following code?

```
CHttpRequest and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getRawBody".
```

The code I am running is as follows:

```
function actionDoSomething() {
   $requestBody = Yii::app()->request->getRawBody();
}
```

I can see the RawBody() function is available from v1.1.13 - so I assue my version shouldn't have any issue with this? Any ideas on why I am getting this error?
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getRawBody-detail

Comment: 1.1.13 is after 1.1.8 so the method doesn't exist in your version of yii

Comment: oops... my eyes are tired...

Comment: I'm not sure if I can update the version... would it be acceptable to just add this exact function locally within the single controller where this is required OR alternatively extend the existing class by creating extended class for the CHTTP::Request

Comment: Hum I see two choices: or you update the whole framework or you extend the class, but really don't update just a single class

Comment: If you want I can post as an answer how to extend the CHttpRequest

Comment: That would be much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58409/discussion-between-darkheir-and-zabs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, with you yii version you can't use this method, so you should extend CHttpRequest to add it:

Create a `HttpRequest` file in your `components` folder

```
class HttpRequest extends CHttpRequest
{

    /**
     * Returns the raw HTTP request body.
     * @return string the request body
     * @since 1.1.13
     */
    public function getRawBody()
    {
        static $rawBody;
        if($rawBody===null)
        $rawBody=file_get_contents('php://input');
        return $rawBody;
    }
}
```

And in your configuration file specify wich request component must be used

```
'components' => array(
    'request'=>array(
        'class' => 'HttpRequest',
    ),
),
```

Comment: I have created a new file called HttpRequest.php and added the code above, I have also added this to the components array in my config.

When I run the same page I get the same CHttpRequest and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named “getRawBody” error, however when I do add the line var_dump(get_class_methods('HttpRequest'));exit; - I can see the getRawBody function in the array?? Any ideas why I'm getting the error

Comment: and what is the output of get_class(Yii::app()->request); ?

Comment: When I echo out echo get_class(Yii::app()->request);

It says 'CHttpRequest'

Comment: Ok so the config is not applied, and Yii still try to use CHttpRequest. In your config, in import you have the components folder? (something like 'application.components.*',) ? And try to clear everything from the runtime folder

Comment: Awesome mate! Our setup has multiple config files (don't ask why) and I added this to the incorrect config file - no error now :)

To test the json - do I just add the json to be outputted directly.. sorry if the question sounds a bit 'noob' like (see my original post in 1min for more info).